# Find all ancestors and children of a process

Tags: bash, unix, recursion

I need to write a recursive function that will take a PID and find its parent, ancestors, and children. I wrote this, but it doesn't seem to work.

This function is only for the ancestors of the process that the user input.

```
findFather(){
if [ $1 -ne 1 ]; then
   pid=$1
   ppid=ps -ef | awk '$pid == $2'
   findFather $ppid
   echo $ppid
fi

findFather $1
```

Comment: first pid is 1 not 0!

Comment: Is this missing single quote after the $2 intentional? E.g. shouldn't it be '$pid == $2'?

Comment: @F.Hauri Still dosent works..

Comment: why not use `ps ho ppid $pid` instead of filtering with awk?

Comment: do you need your own functions? you can use pstree, for example, in order to get parents and children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is my purpose:

```
findFather(){
    ppid=$(ps ho ppid $1)
    echo $ppid
    [ $ppid -gt 1 ] &&  findFather $ppid
}
```

And for the childs:

```
findChilds() {
    for child in $(ps --ppid $1 ho pid) ;do
        echo $child
        findChilds $child
    done
}
```

Same with hierachical presentation:

```
findChilds() {
    for child in $(ps --ppid $1 ho pid);do
        [ $child -eq $$ ] && echo $child Current ||
            echo $child ":(" $(findChilds $child) ")"
    done
}
```

Next step: doing proper indent.

Answer (score 3):

`pstree` from the `psmisc` package:

```
*$ sleep 60 & sleep 60 & sleep 60 &
[1] 2196
[2] 2197
[3] 2198
$ echo $$
1876
$ pstree -sp $$
systemd(1)───gnome-terminal-(3381)───fish(1186)───bash(1876)─┬─pstree(2224)
                                                             ├─sleep(2196)
                                                             ├─sleep(2197)
                                                             └─sleep(2198)*
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use `$(...)` to capture the output of the awk pipeline. Second, use `awk -v` to pass a variable into an awk script.

```
ppid=$(ps -ef | awk -v pid="$pid" 'pid == $2')
```

Alternatively, use double quotes, but then make sure to escape `$2`.

```
ppid=$(ps -ef | awk "$pid == \$2")
```

Comment: John, is the command substitution for `ppid` intended to return the entire line from `ps`? e.g. `ppid` = `david     1521  1483  0 Apr24 pts/2    00:00:01 /bin/bash`? Seems like you would simply want the next `pid` ?

Answer (score 0):

For one your missing the " ' " at the end of the awk statement.

Next you have not closed the function by missing the "}" to define where the function ends.

I'm not sure if you can call the "findFather" function from within that function itself.

What I would suggest is that you run the "ps -ef" command and either awk or grep to get all the lines which contain your PID - store them in an array maybe, then you can awk that array and just grab that PID field for those lines... that should give you the child processes PID's.

Hope that makes some sense, and there may be better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mypid=23264
pstree -aAp $(ps -ejH | awk -v v1=$mypid '$1==v1 {print $3}')
```

Results in something similar :

```
 bash,2342
 `-python,23264 /usr/local/bin/<some command> ...
  `-ssh,25982 -t -x -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oPubkeyAuthentication=n
```

You can do just `pstree -p <other arguments>`. That should print out the `pid` with the program name.

Answer (score 0):

#### first way:

all children of parent (= bash):

```
~ ❱ sleep 10 & sleep 10 & sleep 10 & sleep 10 & 
[2] 6038
[3] 6039
[4] 6040
[5] 6041
~ ❱ pgrep -P $(pgrep -x bash)
4731
6038
6039
6040
6041
~ ❱
```

#### second way:

all children recursively:

```
~ ❱ sleep 10 & sleep 10 & sleep 10 & sleep 10 & 
[2] 6077
[3] 6078
[4] 6079
[5] 6080
~ ❱ ps -o time,pid,ppid,cmd --forest -g -p $(pgrep -x bash)
    TIME   PID  PPID CMD
00:00:01  2986  2984 /bin/bash
00:00:00  4731  2986  \_ redshift
00:00:00  6077  2986  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6078  2986  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6079  2986  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6080  2986  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6082  2986  \_ ps -o time,pid,ppid,cmd --forest -g -p 2986
~ ❱
```

more elegant way by defining a **function** in `.bashrc`

```
function subps()
{
    process=$(pgrep -x $1)
    ps -o time,pid,ppid,cmd --forest -g -p $process
}
```

then on command-line:

```
~ ❱ sleep 10 & sleep 10 & sleep 10 & sleep 10 & 
[1] 6141
[2] 6142
[3] 6143
[4] 6144
~ ❱ subps bash
    TIME   PID  PPID CMD
00:00:00  6126  6124 /bin/bash
00:00:00  6141  6126  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6142  6126  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6143  6126  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6144  6126  \_ sleep 10
00:00:00  6146  6126  \_ ps -o time,pid,ppid,cmd --forest -g -p 6126
~ ❱
```

#### third way:

using `htop` command; then `F3` for search and `F5` for making the list in tree style:

[image: htop]

**NOTE** that the `F5` has two modes: `Tree` and `Sorted`